# SELECT sum from column in json [MARIADB] [LONGTEXT]

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

Guys can you please help me to select sum( values from column where is the JSON string). The **column** looks like this:

**personal_attachment2** (as longtext)

```
[{"file":"FILE.doc",
  "POSITION":"3245",
  "NUMBER":"2345",
  "PRICE":"123",
  "PRICE2":"3456",
  "NUMBER":"2019-01-25",
  "date":"2019\/01\/15",
  "added_by":"admin"
 },{
  "file":"FILE.doc",
  "POSITION":"345",
  "numer_faktury":"456",
  "PRICE":"125",
  "PRICE2":"567",
  "DATE":"2019-01-11",
  "DATE":"2019\/01\/15",
  "added_by":"admin"
}]
```

The name of the table is: **pricing_table**

So I would like to get the sum of the price of all the values in the column.
Just for example:

**sum(PRICE) = 248**

Can I do this using DB-MARIA database? (10.1.37-MariaDB)
What kind of function Can I use?

regards,

Comment: _Small Point_ But `123+125=248`

Comment: i've corrected :)

Comment: Not till 10.2.6 [See this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165522/does-mariadb-support-native-json-column-data-type)

Comment: You want sum for Price and Price 2, other fields ?

Comment: Just only Price - sum two values in the column,

Comment: MariaDB 10.2.3. (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json_extract/ ) + https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/connect-json-table-type/#jsonget_string-jsonget_int-jsonget_real

Comment: This is an argument _against_ hiding things in JSON strings when you eventually need SQL to see the things.